# SQLite database add new table when upgrade app

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I add one more table to my app's database.
However, if I upgrade my app without clearing its data, the new table doesn't seem to be added automatically.
Therefore, some code that need to retrieve data from the new table fail.

Is it possible to add new tables automatically on app upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a method onUpgrade

add you code there and increase database version if your version is higher than the previous
onUpgrade is fired and the your code will execute which you write to add table

### sample

Remember increasing you version code in super call

```
class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public Database(Context _myContext)
    {
    super(_myContext, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        if(oldVersion > newVersion)
        {
            // create a new table what you want to create you can also check the existence of the table
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user538565 In your class constructor which extends your sqliteHelper 

check updates

Answer (score 0):

Please implement [onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onUpgrade%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20int,%20int%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is an Android helper class to manage database creation and version management using an application's raw asset files.

Have a look at this :

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper